# How to increase the middleclick area of the Magic Mouse?

Tags: mouse, click, bettertouchtool

I am using BetterTouchTool to set the gesture "Single middle click" to "Middleclick". I have problems hitting the small middleclick-area of the mouse at once :-/

So is there a way to increase the middleclick-area?

(Alternatively I use a two finger tap as middleclick, but I'd prefer the real thing :-))

Comment: This maybe achieveable with a different App such as http://www.jitouch.com/

Comment: You could also try three finger click as the middle click. It works very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're completely devoted to Better Touch Tool, another option (and one that I've been using myself for the past couple of years) is [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/). It gives you the same functionality as Better Touch Tool, as well as allowing you to set the area on the mouse that responds to the touch gestures.